# Show div under full-height with background from above div

Tags: css, responsive-design

- I got a full-height header with a vertical centered article. This needs to visible first
- Then I got a section with tekst. This section needs to be visible after the header so that the full-height header is visible on any device first and the tekst after it.

But the background of the header needs to extend when you scroll down to the section with the tekst.

Can anybody help me?

*It is neccesary that the header keeps a 100% height , not fixed and is displayed first and that the article keeps vertical centered, the section with tekst needs to have the background from the header when you scroll down*

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/och52kgL/7/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <article>
            Centered title comes here
        </article>
    </header>
    <section>
        Text under window height comes here
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/');
    height: 100%;
}

article {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

section {
    background: green;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Your question is pretty vague, please try to explain it better

Comment: Changed the post is it clear now?

Comment: Is this what you need? - https://jsfiddle.net/och52kgL/10/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand fully, but is this what you're looking for?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

section {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  position:relative;
  top:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <article class="vertical-center">
      Centred title comes here
    </article>
  </header>
  <section>
    Text under window height comes here
  </section>
</body>
```

Your comment makes me believe you want something more like

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
header {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
article {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  background: red;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
section {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <article class="vertical-center">
      Centred title comes here
    </article>
  </header>
  <section>
    Text under window height comes here
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes but then the article (vertical-center) needs to scroll away to make space for the section with text

Answer (score 1):

You could set your header height to:

height: calc(100% + 50px);

Where 50px is, in this example, the height of your `section`, then place the `section`inside the header (as, if I undertood well they are sharing the same `background-image`) and position it `absolute` with `bottom:0`

If `section`is going to have dinamic content (not known height) you then may need to use jquery to calculate the height onload and set the same `cal(100% + XXpx);` trough the script.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/och52kgL/11/)**

**EDITED**: If your `section`content is going to be dinamic, don't set any `height`to your `header`and insteed use this jquery on page load:

```
var sectionHeight = $('section').outerHeight(true );
$('header').css('height', 'calc(100% + ' + sectionHeight + 'px');
```

Which basically will calculate the height of your `section` and then added to the `header` plus `100%`

Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/och52kgL/12/)** /try changing the content of the `section` and press "run" again.

Comment: True, But the problem is that I do never know the height. I need to append since it needs to be responsive and on small devices the text will break down and the div is not heigh anove.

Comment: Updated my answer for dinamic content

Answer (score 0):

Put `background: red;` on `body`.

Comment: Read the question again, that's not what he wants.

Comment: well...that will replace white color and whole page will have background, what is the problem ?

Comment: I chaned my fiddle with an image background. I used red to demo but the text need to be on top of the header image.

Comment: Ok let's use image: https://jsfiddle.net/och52kgL/6/ . Single background image for body with texts above